# Is it possible to prevent controls inheriting the visual style of their container?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have GroupBox with its Font set to bold. If I put a TextBox or DataGridView inside the GroupBox when they are displayed all their text also appears in bold. The contained controls appear to inherit the font style of the container.

How can I stop this happening, i.e. I want the contianed controls to use the font as specified at design time.  I can obviously reset the pertinent properties, but is there an easier way? In other words how do I stop contained controls inheriting such properties?

Thanks

Clarry.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put a `Panel` having the right font inside the `GroupBox` and then put your controls inside this `Panel`.